# jquery set value of javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Ok I now have things partly working. When I click the renewaltype "Renewal" radio button option it checks the nameReservation1 radio button and fires function to update the pricing calculator and reveals the BINnum ID. 
But when I click renewaltype "New Registration" radio button option it doesn't check nameReservation0 radio button but it does update the pricing displayed in my form calculator.

Also, it doesn't change the pricing at all (display amount or the total) when I click the nameReservation options at all. these still need to be independantly clickable but only with the New Registration renewaltype option.

```
<script>
$(function() {
$('.renewaltype').change(function() {
 if($(this).val() == 'New Registration') {$('#BINnum').hide('500');} {$( "#nameReservation0" ).prop( "checked", true );$( "#nameReservation1" ).prop( "checked", false ); checkRadioRT();Form_Calculator();}
if($(this).val() == 'Renewal') {$('#BINnum').show('500');} {$( "#nameReservation1" ).prop( "checked", true );$( "#nameReservation0" ).prop( "checked", false ); checkRadioRT();Form_Calculator();}
});
});
</script>  

 <script>
 $(function() {
 $('.nameReservation').change(function() {
 if($(this).val() == 'With Mandatory Name Reservation'){$('#dispNoReserve').hide('500');} {checkRadioNR();Form_Calculator();}
 if($(this).val() == 'Without Mandatory Name Reservation') {$('#dispNoReserve').show('500');} {checkRadioNR();Form_Calculator();} 
 });
 });
 </script>
```

Javascript function called

```
function checkRadioNR() { 
var i;
//checking which radio button selected 
for ( i = 0;  i < theForm.nameReservation.length; i++) {

if (theForm.nameReservation[i].checked == true) {   
    switch(i)
    {
        case 0:         
        theForm.price_NR.value = accounting.formatMoney('45.00');
        price_NR = 45.00;       
        break

        case 1:             
        theForm.price_NR.value = accounting.formatMoney('');
        price_NR = 0;
        break
       }            
     }
     }  
     } 


  function checkRadioRT() { 
  var i;
  //checking which radio button selected 
  for ( i = 0;  i < theForm.renewaltype.length; i++) {

   if (theForm.renewaltype[i].checked == true) {   
    switch(i)
    {
        case 0:         
        theForm.price_NR.value = accounting.formatMoney('45.00');
        price_NR = 45.00;       
        //document.getElementById("NUANS").checked = true;
        break

        case 1:             
        theForm.price_NR.value = accounting.formatMoney('');
        price_NR = 0;
        document.getElementById("nameReservation1").checked  == true;
        //document.getElementById("NUANS").checked = false;
        break
        }           
        }
        }   
        } 

function checkRadioNR() { 
var i;
//checking which radio button selected 
for ( i = 0;  i < theForm.nameReservation.length; i++) {

 if (theForm.nameReservation[i].checked == true) {   
    switch(i)
    {
        case 0:         
        theForm.price_NR.value = accounting.formatMoney('45.00');
        price_NR = 45.00;       
        //document.getElementById("NUANS").checked = true;
        break

        case 1:             
        theForm.price_NR.value = accounting.formatMoney('');
        price_NR = 0;
        //document.getElementById("NUANS").checked = false;
        break
       }            
       }
       }    
       }
```

HTML Code for Radio button

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="radio">
          <label>
        <input name="nameReservation" class="nameReservation" id="nameReservation1" type="radio" onClick="checkCheckbox(); Form_Calculator();" value="Without Mandatory Name Reservation">
               <span class="custom-check2"></span> <strong>Without Mandatory Name Reservation</strong>
           </label>
        </div>                
        </div>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. If you want to call `Form_Calculator` then you just use `Form_Calculator();` to call the function.

Comment: Asking questions without using a `?` is a bit odd. What was your problem again`?`

Comment: Ok I edited my code and the problems I am having....

When I click renewaltype "New Registration" radio button option it doesn't check nameReservation0 radio button but it does update the pricing displayed in my form calculator.

Also, it doesn't change the pricing at all (display amount or the total) when I click the nameReservation options at all. These still need to be independantly clickable but only with the New Registration renewaltype option.